# Can only one page of http web application use WebSocket

Tags: websocket

I am planning to use websockets on a page in a normal web application, for displaying a large amount of data.
Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is feasible to just use websockets on one page of your website.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Websockets are a utility you can use in any web application.